# Latest newtx package update (v1.601 Oct 2, 2019) breaks the footnote command [update: bug fixed by package author]

Tags: fonts, packages, footnotes, bugs, newtx

The latest `newtxtext` package (v1.601 Oct 2, 2019) seems to have broken the `\footnote` command.

Here's a MWE

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}  % <------ comment this line to get a successful compilation

\begin{document}

Testing Footnotes\footnote{This is a test for the footnote command}.

\end{document}
```

When compiled with `pdflatex`, I get the following error message

> !pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file ntxsups_T1.enc): cannot open encoding file for re
>   ading
>    ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

This file is located at `/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/newtx/ntxsups_t1.enc` (the suspicious part being that it is located under the `dvips` folder).

How can I workaround this issue?

#### Update 1

The author/maintainer of `newtx` has acknowledged this issue and have said that they shall be issuing a fix soon.

#### Update 2

The package author/maintainer has confirmed that a version with a fix for this issue has just been uploaded to CTAN. I wish to thank them for their prompt response on this.

Thanks to the helpful members here who provided workarounds in this matter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is quite normal that the `enc` file is located in the `dvips` sub-tree. The problem here is that the `map` file requests `ntxsups_T1.enc` but the actual file is called `ntxsups_t1.enc`. This is no problem on case-insensitive file systems. As a work-around I would try (untested):

```
$ mkdir -p ~/texmf/fonts/enc/dvips/newtx
$ cp /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/newtx/ntxsups_t1.enc \
    ~/texmf/fonts/enc/dvips/newtx/ntxsups_T1.enc
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. That works! Can you please elaborate on `case-insensitive` filesystems? I am on GNU/Linux. But does that mean that the package update broke all existing documents on Linux for all users worldwide?

Comment: @Krishna Windows and I believe MacOS use case-insensitive file systems. Yes, I believe this update broke all footnote using documents on Linux systems. Somebody should report it to the package author.

Comment: thank you. I have emailed the package author about this.

Comment: The problem is in the file `newtx.map` that TeX Live uses for rebuilding `pdftex.map`; the fix should be done on that file, rather than copying files. For instance, your fix would not work on macOS, which is case sensitive, but doesn't allow two files differing only by letter casing in the same directory.

Comment: @egreg Why do you think the file names are correct and the map file is wrong? Anyway, for a *work-around* changing the file name is much easier than changing map files. Also, the two files are not in the same directory so I don't expect problems on MacOS.

Comment: OK, they're not in the same place; but one should remember to remove them when the package is updated.

Answer (score 7):

The `newtx` distribution provides the file `newtx.map` for rebuilding the main map files (mainly `pdftex.map`). In this file we read

```
ntxsups-Regular-ot1 ntxsups-Regular " ntxsupsOT1Encoding ReEncodeFont " <[ntxsups_OT1.enc <ntxsups-Regular.pfb
ntxsups-Regular-t1 ntxsups-Regular " ntxsupsT1Encoding ReEncodeFont " <[ntxsups_T1.enc <ntxsups-Regular.pfb
ntxsups-Regular-ly1 ntxsups-Regular " ntxsupsLY1Encoding ReEncodeFont " <[ntxsups_LY1.enc <ntxsups-Regular.pfb
ntxsups-Italic-ot1 ntxsups-Italic " ntxsupsOT1Encoding ReEncodeFont " <[ntxsups_OT1.enc <ntxsups-Italic.pfb
ntxsups-Italic-t1 ntxsups-Italic " ntxsupsT1Encoding ReEncodeFont " <[ntxsups_T1.enc <ntxsups-Italic.pfb
ntxsups-Italic-ly1 ntxsups-Italic " ntxsupsLY1Encoding ReEncodeFont " <[ntxsups_LY1.enc <ntxsups-Italic.pfb
ntxsups-Bold-ot1 ntxsups-Bold " ntxsupsOT1Encoding ReEncodeFont " <[ntxsups_OT1.enc <ntxsups-Bold.pfb
ntxsups-Bold-t1 ntxsups-Bold " ntxsupsT1Encoding ReEncodeFont " <[ntxsups_T1.enc <ntxsups-Bold.pfb
ntxsups-Bold-ly1 ntxsups-Bold " ntxsupsLY1Encoding ReEncodeFont " <[ntxsups_LY1.enc <ntxsups-Bold.pfb
ntxsups-BoldItalic-ot1 ntxsups-BoldItalic " ntxsupsOT1Encoding ReEncodeFont " <[ntxsups_OT1.enc <ntxsups-BoldItalic.pfb
ntxsups-BoldItalic-t1 ntxsups-BoldItalic " ntxsupsT1Encoding ReEncodeFont " <[ntxsups_T1.enc <ntxsups-BoldItalic.pfb
ntxsups-BoldItalic-ly1 ntxsups-BoldItalic " ntxsupsLY1Encoding ReEncodeFont " <ntxsups_LY1.enc <ntxsups-BoldItalic.pfb
```

but the corresponding files are named

```
ntxsups_ot1.enc
ntxsups_t1.enc
ntxsups_ly1.enc
```

The `newtx.map` file should be fixed to contain the correct names. The problem doesn't show up on Windows systems, that are case insensitive.

With suitable privileges open

```
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/map/dvips/newtx/newtx.map
```

Fix the faulty entries shown above changing the file names to match the distributed ones, save and, again with suitable privileges, run

```
updmap -sys
```

Once the package is updated, the fix will disappear, whatever method the package maintainer will choose to use in order to correct the faulty behavior.

The fix has been tested.

Comment: thank you. The maintainer has acknowledged this issue and said that they shall be issuing a fix soon.